# neither kubuntu 13.04 nor ubuntu 12.04 can detect network (wired/wireless) activity

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 13.04, networking, kubuntu

Thanks for reading, i have an HP mini 110-1030LA, it had Windows XP, tottaly functional, a little slow but funtional, i decided to install kubuntu saucy (32 bits), everythings seems to be better, the speed increased sustantialy, but it couldn't detect neither wireless nor wired networks.
I decided to try (not installing) ubuntu  12.04 (32 bits) on a live usb disk, but the problem prevails.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu go to Software Sources, select Additional Drivers tab and if there's any driver listed for your network cards, install it.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to have ubuntu configured to use a static ip on first boot.

Verify that /etc/network/interfaces is changed from this:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

to this:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

http://spuder.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/ubuntu-12-04-networking-on-fresh-install/